# How do you get the index of a key in a array by and if value contains?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Here's my what I meant.

```
var brands = [['brand: LV'], ['brand: Apple']]...
```

With this, I want to position(index) of say..Apple. Manually, I can easily do

```
brands[1]
```

But this gets dynamically updated, therefor the index will be random.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.  Did you mean `var brands = [ { 'brand': 'LV'}, { 'brand': 'Apple'}, ... ]`?  (Answer: `brands.findIndex( element => return 0 == element.brand.localeCompare('Apple'))`)

Comment: So basically you wanted to do `brands.apple` and get that object. Just restructure everything, and use the brands as keys

Comment: …or do you mean `var brands = [['brand: LV'], ['brand: Apple'], ...]`

Comment: Sorry I meant, [['brand: LV'], ['brand: Apple']], brand is not an object, it's part of the value

Comment: That's valid, but strange, using arrays for what looks like something that should be objects

Comment: Algolia's API...

Comment: So is this something you're going to be using a lot, on the same dataset? If so, restructure, create an object with the brands as keys, much easier if you need to look something up more than a couple of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is a little inconvenient, normally you would have an array of objects not an array of strings like this, but at any rate you can still:

```js
let brands = [ ['brand: LV'],['brand: Apple']]
let f = brands.findIndex(subarray => subarray.some(i => i.includes('Apple')))
console.log(f, brands[f])
```

Note that since you have these arrays it accounts for the possibility of one of them having more than one value. So consider:

```js
let  brands = [['brand: LV'], ['brand: Sony', 'brand: Apple']]
let f = brands.findIndex(subarray => subarray.some(i => i.includes('Apple')))
console.log(f, brands[f])
```

If you know each subarray will only have one value, you can just test for that:

```js
let brands = [ ['brand: LV'],['brand: Apple']]
let f = brands.findIndex(subarray => subarray[0].includes('Apple'))
console.log(f, brands[f])
```

Comment: Yes, sadly this is how Algolia's API works. Let me try this!

Comment: Boom! Thank you so much!

Comment: Using `.includes()` in this manner will give false positives when a test value is a substring of a larger name.  "Intel" probably doesn't want to be confused for "Intelius"

Answer (score 0):

Use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Example : `brands.findIndex(doc => doc[0] === 'brand: Apple')`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is an array of arrays, a simple `includes` or `indexOf` won't work on the top level, you need to test each element.  Using `findIndex` allows you to apply a custom function to each element in turn:

```js
let brands = [
  ['brand: LV'],
  ['brand: Apple']
];

function findBrand(name) {
    let testValue = `brand: ${name}`;
    return brands.findIndex( elem => elem.includes(testValue) );
}

console.log(findBrand('Apple'))
```

Comment: Boom! Thank you so much!